# Push notification setup for iOS apps in ionic cordova and firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have success in using push notification service in android apps and ionic.

But I am a new developer in apple territory.
I have no idea how Xcode works, and after some tweaking around and research, I managed to create an IPA file and installed the app on an iPhone.

But I am not able to have success on the push notification front.

And I am a lot in confusion with the certificates and capabilities in Xcode while creating an iOS app with push notification enabled.

Can anyone guide me on how to create an iOS app with firebase push notification enabled and working, and the correct steps to build one in ionic Cordova and Xcode.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use [this](https://medium.com/@felipepucinelli/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-your-cordova-application-using-firebase-69fac067e821)

but in my case [Onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup) works better